# preg_match assistance needed

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi I need assistance changing the preg_match to check for 2-16chars A-z 0-9 -_ and space. Right now its checking URL so i'd need to remove the protocol, add space and 2-16 min/max chr.

```
public function checkUrl($string)
{
    if(empty($string) || preg_match("#^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(d+)?/?#i", $string))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if( isset($this) )
        {
            $this->addError("Input Error");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what part you want to change, but...

> [Need to match] 2-16 chars A-z 0-9 -_ and space.

```
[\w- ]{2,16}
```

- `\w` matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.
- `-` will match the literal `-` in a character class outside of a valid range.
- `'  '` will match a space (ignore quotes, Stack Overflow needed them to display). To match any whitespace character, use `\s`.
- `{2,16}` will quantify the match to be between 2 and 16 times inclusively.
- You could also change `(http|https|ftp)` to `(?:https?|ftp)`, which won't capture the group, as you aren't using any back references.

Comment: Beat me to it. Only thing: Doesn't the dash have to come first? Or, if it doesn't make a valid range, is it just interpreted as literal?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc Matches fine in my test :) If it is not a valid range, it is considered a literal.

Answer (score 2):

[According to regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), there are some things you can do:

- A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _ can all be matched with `\w`
- Min/max can be done with brackets `{min, max}`

So to check for "2-16chars A-z 0-9 -_ and space" we'd have to do something like this:

```
[- \w]{2,16}
```